# Send email to administrators upon locked out user in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I need to have Sitecore send an email to a particular email address whenever a user gets locked out of Sitecore by entering an incorrect password too many times. I have code to send an email; however, I don't see a pipeline that fires during the login process (loggedin and loggingin only fire upon successful login).

Comment: Are you looking for locked out users in the Sitecore domain or users from an external membership provider?

Comment: @WesleyLomax: Sitecore domain.

Comment: @EdSchwehm have you seen my answer below? does it work for you?

Comment: @Maras: I haven't had a chance to test it yet. I asked this question as a prelude to doing the actual development. But, rest assured, I will be testing your and OptimizedQuery's solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to modify @Maras's answer a little bit to get it to work as the domain is not prefixed to the UserName property in the LoggingIn Event. Other than that the code works great.

```
namespace My.Namespace.Login
{
    public class CustomLoginPage : LoginPage
    {
        private bool _userIsNotLockedOut;

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            Login.LoggingIn += Login_LoggingIn;
            Login.LoginError += Login_LoginError;
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void Login_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string domainUser = Login.UserName;
            if (!domainUser.Contains("sitecore\\"))
            {
                var domain = Sitecore.Context.Domain;
                domainUser = domain + @"\" + domainUser;
            }

            var user = Membership.GetUser(domainUser, false);

            if (user != null)
            {
                _userIsNotLockedOut = !user.IsLockedOut;
            }
        }

        private void Login_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_userIsNotLockedOut)
            {
                var user = Membership.GetUser(Login.UserName, false);
                if (user != null && user.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    SendEmail();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to reference the Sitecore.Client.dll, testing done in Sitecore 7.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that you're using standard **Sitecore** login page.

I managed to achieve what you need with overriding **Sitecore** login page. What you need to do is to create a class which inherits from `Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage` (it's not a typo) class and then add 2 methods which will be executed before logging in to the system and after login failed as follows:

```
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
  public class MyLoginPage : LoginPage
  {
    private bool maybeWillBeLockedOut;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
      Login.LoggingIn += Login_LoggingIn;
      Login.LoginError += Login_LoginError;
      base.OnInit(e);
    }

    void Login_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
      MembershipUser user = Membership.Provider.GetUser(Login.UserName, false);
      // user with username exists and is not locked out yet
      maybeWillBeLockedOut = user != null && !user.IsLockedOut;
    }

    void Login_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (maybeWillBeLockedOut)
      {
        // login failed - lets check if locked out now
        MembershipUser user = Membership.Provider.GetUser(Login.UserName, false);
        if (user != null && user.IsLockedOut)
        {
          // user wasn't locked out but is now - send an email
          SendEmail();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then update **sitecore\login\default.aspx** file and set the new class in **Inherits** attribute:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="My.Assembly.Namespace.MyLoginPage" %>
```

This is not the most elegant solution but as you and @OptimizedQuery noticed, `LoggingIn` and `LoggedIn` pipelines are not sufficient in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom pipeline process just before the `Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckStartPage, Sitecore.Kernel` processor in the `loggingin` pipeline process.  When I entered a valid username and invalid password, my breakpoint was hit before I was notified that my login was unsuccessful.  If your custom processor comes after the `CheckStartPage` processor, then it would only get hit upon successful login because the `CheckStartPage` process aborts the pipeline if the username/password combination fails validation.  I am unsure how to check for a locked out user but it appears you should be able to add your processor before the `CheckStartPage` processor or override that processor.

My testing and Reflecting was done on a Sitecore 6.6 solution.